# Date picker not working on jQuery CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
         <label class="control-label">Expected Date</label>
         <div class="input-group date form_datetime form_datetime bs-datetime">
            <input id="access_from" name="access_from" size="16" class="form-control" id="from" type="date">
            <span  class="input-group-addon">
               <button id="click" class="btn default date-set" type="button"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
             </span>
        </div>
    </div>   
</div>
```

jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#click").click(function() {
            $("#access_from").datepicker("show");
        });
    });
</script>
```

From this code, my date picker is not opening. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure its going in to click event on click of button?

Comment: yes its going therw

Comment: check your console for errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adding `id` attribute twice in your input element.
Remove `id="from"` and [type="date"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date)(which has specific date formats) and use the below

```
 <input id="access_from" name="access_from" size="16" class="form-control" />
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#click").click(function() {
    $("#access_from").datepicker("show");
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Expected Date</label>
    <div class="input-group date form_datetime form_datetime bs-datetime">
      <input id="access_from" name="access_from" size="16" class="form-control"/>
      <span class="input-group-addon">
          <button id="click" class="btn default date-set" type="button"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove the `type="date"` Try my updated answer and snippet.